# Dynamic addition to an Excel formula / Dynamic search and replace

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

First time posting here, so sorry if I'm missing something. If so please let me know.

So, the issue at hand:
I have a lot of formulas (thousands) that I need to change/add to, but I'm unsure how/what the smartest way to do it is.

All the formulas look something like:

```
=C5+D5-S5
```

But some of them have an additional part after the basic formula, it could be multiple things, but an example is:

```
=C829+D829-S829 +T834+T835+T835+(T836*2)
```

Or

```
=C1101+D1101-S1101 +T1102
```

I'd like to change the basic part to:

```
=C5+D5+E5+F5+G5+H5-S5
```

Or perhaps

```
=SUM(C5:H5)-S5
```

While still keeping the additional part that might be there after "-Sx"

I'm using Excel 2016 64-bit.
I've played around with search and replace without much success.
I have a little experience using VBA, so maybe that's the way to solve this.
The formula might need to be changed again in the future.

Comment: Yes, VBA is the answer to your question. What have you written so far?

Comment: Nothing to be honest, as I wasn't really sure VBA was the answer.
What functionality in VBA do I need to make use of? And would it be possible to code something that would work again for further changes to the formula?

Comment: You will need to get a reference to a cell and its formula. After that, it is time to change the formula according to your logic. Once that is working, start to think on how to do this to all cells

Comment: For changing the formula, all you need is some operations on string: finding character in string, taking part of it etc.

Comment: So I've made a bit of code and it runs through each row, returning the formula as a string that I can manipulate in VBA. However, I don't have much/any experience "making operations on a string" as Egan Wolf put it. I guess what I need to do is find the -Sx part and change that and anything before it to my updated formula, while keeping anything after the -Sx part. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to do this? And thanks for the replies btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to make some VBA that did the job - and with a bit of tweaking I'll be able to reuse it if needed later on.

Thanks for the input! The final code is posted below.

```
Sub RPLF()
    Dim idr As Range
    Dim crp As Double
    Dim lrp As Double
    Dim form As String
    Dim newform As String

    crp = 4

    With Worksheets("S-S")
        lrp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With

    For Each idr In Range("A4:" & "A" & lrp)
         crp = crp + 1
         form = Worksheets("S-S").Range("T" & crp).Formula
         newform = Replace(form, "=C" & crp & "+D" & crp & "-S" & crp, "=SUM(C" & crp & ":H" & crp & ")-S" & crp)
         Worksheets("S-S").Range("T" & crp).Formula = newform
    Next
End Sub
```